# Cressman interpolation and objective analysis

Tags: interpolation, numerics

I have read this question and answer – [Interpolation of scattered data to a regular grid in python](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/12057/how-to-interpolate-scattered-data-to-a-regular-grid-in-python) and I am doing something similar as I have temperature values of the atmosphere at different heights defined on a  coarse grid  and I want to interpolate this to a regular grid in Python and I also need to weight the matches using the Cressman weighting scheme as shown in this old paper – [Cressman weighting scheme](ftp://ftp.library.noaa.gov/docs.lib/htdocs/rescue/mwr/087/mwr-087-10-0367.pdf).

In this regard, I have a couple of questions. Looking at equation (1)

$$C_h =  -W  E_h$$

I understand what $W$ is and how to go about calculating it but it is not clear to me what the author means when he writes:

> $E_h$ is the error of the interpolated value of the first guess field at the location of the observation

An error is usually a difference between two values. If that is the case which two values are being referred to here? As a first guess, I have my temperature values at irregular grid intervals and I can easily find matches within a radius of influence for a particular grid point. But which two values are contributing to the error that is being talked about here?

I have also read papers (cf. [Vertical and horizontal Cressman radii](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0493%281998%29126%3C0393%3ATGCKSD%3E2.0.CO%3B2)) in which it is mentioned that the radius of influence that Cressman talks about in the above paper sometimes can be treated as a "deep layer" in the atmospheric sciences. In other words, the interpolated value at a grid point can include matches from not only the horizontal radius of influence on a given horizontal surface but also matches from above and below the surface in question. Is that accurate?